# Issue with finding average in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
import sqlite3
import csv

conn=sqlite3.connect("D:/asdfef.xdb")

cur=conn.cursor()

cur.execute("select max(ue_rsrp) from  lte_ue_rf") #sql query to calculate the avergae

rows = cur.fetchall() 

columns = [i[0] for i in cur.description]

with open("D:/asdf.csv",'w') as file:
   writer=csv.writer(file)
   writer.writerow(columns)
   writer.writerow(rows)
```

Above is the code used to retrieve the avg of an item in the DB, but my output shows up as a list (-79.25,). 
Why is this happening and what should be done to rectify this.
I am a beginner with python coding

Comment: Hi Sarith, Can you please provide the sample data from table, as the query is simply fetching the max value from table.

Comment: RI UE_RSRP
1 -102
2 -86
3 -97
4 -76.2
5 -75.4

Comment: Did you mean `avg` instead of `max` in code? Do you get one-element list or is there something else? See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43355266/calculate-a-mean-with-python-sqlite3-using-the-cursor)